# "function" is not defined , ASP .NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Делаю проект на ASP .NET. Хотел сделать типо слайдер с использованием JS. Просто менять картинки по клику на img
Картинки хранятся на сервере, в ViewModel лежит IEnumerable с картинками (название файла в поле Name).
При вызове JS функции в консоли пишется ошибка об отсутствии  функции. скрипт находится в частичном представлении товара. При клике на любой товар должна меняться картинка.
код:

```
@model Access_Models.ViewModels.IndividualProductVM
@using Access_Utility


<div class="a-IPC-containet filter @Model.Product.Category.Name.Replace(' ','_')">
    <!-- Card-->
    <div class="a-IPC-img-container">
        <img onclick="changeImage(this)" src="@WebConstants.ProductImagePath@Model.Product.Id\@Model.ProductImages.ToArray()[Model.SliderImageIndex].Name" alt="Card image cap" />
    </div>

    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@Model.Product.Id" class="a-IPC-detail-container">
        <div class="a-IPC-detail-container-item">
            <div class="a-IPC-name-text">@Model.Product.Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="a-IPC-detail-container-item">
            <div class="a-IPC-name-price">@string.Format("{0:c}", Model.Product.Price) </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>


@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeImage(el) {
            @Model.SliderImageIndex++;
            @if (Model.SliderImageIndex > Model.ProductImages.Count()) Model.SliderImageIndex = 0;
            el.src = @WebConstants.ProductImagePath@Model.Product.Id\@Model.ProductImages.ToArray()[Model.SliderImageIndex].Name;
         }
    </script>
}
```